# React JS: How to get the data from 2 components in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to get the data from an input to a label to display the value onChange, but that don't work when the 2 component are in array:

```
let expForm = [
    <ExperienceForm
      statePosition={(e) => setPosition(e.target.value)}
      stateCompany={(e) => setCompany(e.target.value)}
      stateCity={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
      stateFrom={(e) => setFrom(e.target.value)}
      stateTo={(e) => setTo(e.target.value)}
    />,
  ];

  let expDisplay = [
    <DisplayExperience
      statePosition={position}
      stateCompany={company}
      stateCity={city}
      stateFrom={from}
      stateTo={to}
    />,
  ];
```

I get and change the value like this:

```
  const [position, setPosition] = useState("Position");
  const [company, setCompany] = useState("Company");
  const [city, setCity] = useState("City");
  const [from, setFrom] = useState("From");
  const [to, setTo] = useState("To");
```

But I want to dynamically add and delete with this function that I call with a button:

```
  const [experienceForm, setExperienceForm] = useState(expForm);
  const [experienceDisplay, setExperienceDisplay] = useState(expDisplay);

  const addComponent = () => {
    setExperienceForm([...experienceForm, expForm]);
    setExperienceDisplay([...experienceDisplay, expDisplay]);
  };
```

and I display them this way:

```
{experienceForm}
{experienceDisplay}
```

I'm new to React Js so feel free to pick me up on things that are obvious to you, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused, what's the rational of putting two components inside an array? Wouldn't it just be easier to keep the data in the array and then map the data to a component?

Comment: I've also noticed you're storing components in state. I would read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919014/is-it-a-good-idea-to-store-components-in-state

Comment: Thank you for the time taken, I will look at all this.