# React: Setting a state of type ReactNode crashes the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I want to dynamically render a component based on what the user has clicked. I tried something like this:

```
function ComponentTest() {
    const [component, setComponent] = useState<ReactNode | null>(null);


    return <button onClick={() => setComponent(SomeFunctionalComponent)}>Crash</button>
}
```

In this example I'm obviously not doing anything with the state, but clicking this button results in the application crashing with the following error messages:

```
Warning: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function. For more information, see https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks
```

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by EinstellungenTest. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks
```

```
Warning: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function. For more information, see https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks
```

```
Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
```

```
The above error occurred in the <ComponentTest> component:
```

Now, I could just write

```
return <button onClick={() => setComponent(<SomeFunctionalComponent/>)}>Crash</button>
```

instead, but I think that creates the component too early. I want to create the component during the render, like this:

```
function ComponentTest() {
    const [component, setComponent] = useState<ReactNode | null>(null);


    return <component/>
}
```

I hope someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hold the value of what component you want to use in the state and then use conditional rendering to render the one you want.

Something like this

```
function ComponentTest() {
  const [componentId, setComponentId] = useState<string | null>(null);


    return <button onClick={() => setComponent("myId")}> {componentId === "myId" && < SomeFunctionalComponent  /> }</button>
}
```

Comment: I guess I could do that, yeah, but then I'll have to add a condition for every component that might be rendered (which will be 10+ at least), and I feel like there's gotta be a better solution

Comment: Marked as correct because it appears to be the intended way of doing things according to this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919014/is-it-a-good-idea-to-store-components-in-state)

Comment: not 100% sure I understand what you are doing but something like this might be a good solution.

const [components, setComponents] = useState<string[]>([]);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
  <button onClick={() => setComponent([...componentId, ...['a'])}>
  { componentId.find((item) => item === 'a') ?? <SomeFunctionalComponentA> }
  </button>
  
    </div>
  );
}