# How to use useState with dynamically added elements?

Tags: reactjs

I have a canvas and when i click on it, it draws a line.

Line is a function:

```
const line = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
  return (
    <line id="lineD" x1={x1} y1={y1} x2={x2} y2={y2} style={{ stroke: "black", strokeWidth: 3, strokeLinecap: "round" }}></line>
    )
}
```

It works fine, except when I scale the canvas. When I do so, I change a `scale` state.

So I want line attributes to be like this: `x1={x1 * scale}`, but it only sets it once.

This is how I add lines, (content is another state):

```
content.push(line(100, 100, 200, 200))
```

(these are just random numbers)
And svg is: `<svg>{content}</svg>`

Comment: Don't push components into state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is "reacting" only to state or props update. Since your `line` function returns JSX, you should turn it into a real React component and pass your data as props to make the rendering dynamic. Something like that:

```
const Line = (props) => {
  const {x1, y1, x2, y2, scale} = props;
  return (
    <line id="lineD" x1={x1 * scale} y1={y1 * scale} x2={x2 * scale} y2={y2 * scale} style={{ stroke: "black", strokeWidth: 3, strokeLinecap: "round" }}></line>
  );
}
```

Note the uppercase L in `Line`: this is mandatory for React to see it as a component. Then you may use it to produce your array:

```
content.push(<Line x1={100} y2={100} x2={200} y2={200} scale={scale} />)
```

But a state should not be muted. You should use the set function you get from `useState`:

```
const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

...

// do the following in an event handler, or in a useEffect
setContent([...content, <Line x1={100} y2={100} x2={200} y2={200} scale={scale} />]);
```

This will update the state and trigger a new rendering

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could you write where I should add scale state, so that when I scale the svg, the line attributes (x1 x2 y1 y2) will change?

Comment: @PavelFedorovsky there are various options: I edited my answer with a possible version ;)

Comment: I have done everything, just like you wrote, but the Line jsx element only renders once and when the scale state changes nothing happens. Do you know what migth be the reason of that?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments it is not a good practice to store components in state.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66946183) explains why.

> Storing elements for later use directly breaks this core concept. You risk having stale elements that do not correspond to the current set of properties.

Instead you could store the *data points* of the lines.

```js
const [content, setContent] = [
  {
    x1: 100,
    y1: 100,
    x2: 100,
    y2: 100,
  },
];

const [scale, setScale] = useState(1);
```

Your `Line` component

```js
const Line = ({ x1, y1, x2, y2, scale }) => {
  return (
    <line
      id="lineD"
      x1={x1 * scale}
      y1={y1 * scale}
      x2={x2 * scale}
      y2={y2 * scale}
      style={{ stroke: "black", strokeWidth: 3, strokeLinecap: "round" }}
    ></line>
  );
};
```

When rendering the lines you can simply `map` over the `content` and add the props to the `Line` component

```js
<svg>
  {content.map((lineData) => {
    return <Line {...lineData} scale={scale} />;
  })}
</svg>
```