# How do renders happen when a component is in a state variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to render different components based on different conditions. To avoid having a bunch of condition renders in my return for a component, I want to use a state variable based and update it when I need to.

So I know that whenever a state variable is changed, the component using that variable and it's subcomponents are re-rendered. But what happens if I have a component inside a state variable?

```
export const Component = (): JSX.Element => {
  let [currentComponent, setCurrentComponent] = useState<JSX.Element>(<SomeComponent />)

  return (
    <div>
      {currentComponent}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is the return of SomeComponent (or more specifically the DOM node that gets outputted from render) static from when setCurrentComponent is called? If a state variable inside of `SomeComponent` gets changed, does that cause everything to get re-rendered?

Comment: *"I need to render different components based on different conditions."* Are these different components passed the same properties? (aka adhere to the same interface) So `<ComponentA name="foo" />` could be swapped out for a different component with the same properties `<ComponentB name="foo" />`. Or do these components have different interfaces?

Comment: @3limin4t0r They have different interfaces, but are controlled by the same condition (ex: which tab is clicked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store component in state, it's a bad practice.
[Is it a good idea to store components in state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919014/is-it-a-good-idea-to-store-components-in-state)

here is how you can conditionally render a component :

```
export const Component = (): JSX.Element => {

 const yourCondition = true

  return (
    <div>
      { yourCondition && (<SomeComponent />) }
    </div>
  )
}
```

here is how you can render different components based on condition :

```
export const Component = (): JSX.Element => {

 const yourCondition = 'bar'

 const render = () => {
  switch(yourCondition){
    case 'foo':
      return <Foo />
    case 'bar':
      return <Bar />
    default:
      return null
  }
 }

  return (
    <div>
      { render() }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is it bad to render a component in state? What I want to avoid is a return statement like that that has 5+ different conditions

Comment: yes, you should avoid it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919014/is-it-a-good-idea-to-store-components-in-state

Comment: I just updated my answer to include an example where I render a different component based on conditions

Comment: Ahh ok, refactoring it into a function w/ switch case is much more concise. Thank you!