# React setState timing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm working on a memory game with cards on React. The game is about clicking on cards without any repetition to get points, if you click on a card twice you pretty much lose. Now, this is an educational project from [The Odin Project](https://www.theodinproject.com) and its goal is to practice React states.

**Problem description**

`App` stores which cards are clicked like a game manager. `Set` shuffles cards and emulates putting them on the table so to say. `Card` a just cards that are in charge of trigger App `checkClicked(name)` function to update which cards have been clicked. My idea at the beginning was to store clicked cards in a state to keep track of user's interaction.

I could pass down `checkClicked(name)` function to `Card` so `Set` could send any of its cards name as a function argument. Why didn't I just trigger `checkClicked(name)` from `Set`. Good question, the problem is that Card `name` prop can't be passed as an argument straight away, hope that makes sense.

Let's get to the point, shall we? I know states work asynchronously so the issue is that if `clicked` was a state, it wouldn't be updated whereas declaring `clicked` as a variable easily solves the whole issue. Why is that? Ideally I should use states to work with data that changes over time but I've also read on some Stackoverflow related posts that a variable would do instead. That makes me ask, when should I go for states then?

*App.js*

```
import './App.css';
import Set from './components/set';
import Score from './components/score';
import {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  let clicked = []

  function checkClicked(name){
    alert(`Calling ${name} from app.js`)
    if(clicked[4]){
      //Reset clicked - current score - best score
    }else{
      if(clicked.find(click => click === name)){
        //Reset current score
        alert('Found')
      }
      else{
        //Update clicked - Check best - increase current
        clicked.push(name)    
      }
    }
    alert(clicked);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Score/>
      <Set action={checkClicked}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*Set.js*

```
import {useState} from "react";
import uniqid from "uniqid";
import Card from "./card";

export default function Set(props){
  const[cards,setCards] = useState([<Card key={uniqid()} onClick={handleAction} name="John" pic="1"/>,
                                    <Card key={uniqid()} onClick={handleAction} name="Al" pic="2"/>,
                                    <Card key={uniqid()} onClick={handleAction} name="Paul" pic="3"/>,
                                    <Card key={uniqid()} onClick={handleAction} name="James" pic="4"/>,
                                    <Card key={uniqid()} onClick={handleAction} name="Lou" pic="5"/>,]);

  function handleAction(name){
    props.action(name);
    shuffle();
  }

  function shuffle(){
    const shuffled = Array(5);
    let random;
    cards.forEach(card=>{
      while(true){
        random = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
        if(!shuffled[random]){
          shuffled[random] = card;
          break;
        }
      }
    });
    setCards(shuffled);
  }
  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={()=>shuffle()}>Shuffle</button>
      {cards}
    </>
  );
  
}
```

*Card.js*

```
export default function Card(props){
 
  function handleClick(){
    props.onClick(props.name);
  }

  return(
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      <p>{props.name}</p>
      <p>{props.pic}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm confident the project structure is right but I'd also like to ask you guys for a review cause maybe there's something I don't see now that has a negative effect and also a link to the problem I'm describing.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use states whenever a state change change could trigger a re-render. In your example, you just use clicked to do some calculation, which doesn't require a re-render. If instead you displayed the clicked list in JSX, you would need to put it in a state.

p.s. I noticed you are storing components in your state in Set.js. This is frowned upon (see [Is it a good idea to store components in state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919014/is-it-a-good-idea-to-store-components-in-state))

Comment: Hey Francis! Thanks for your answer! It makes the whole thing clearer now. I'm checking out your link. Have a good one!

Comment: can I bother you with another question' Just read the "is is a good idea to store components in state?" and it made sense as well but I was wondering if there was a way to reflect `Card` as an object and `Set` as a container of cards. Again this might be a case for a variable but I wouldn't be able to shufflle (change cards render order)

Comment: Never mind, a card should be an object literal with a name and a variable. That way I could avoid using a complete component for it.