Need to store JSX in React state
I want to store React component in React state but I think it is technically wrong. What you think about that?
Example
const LayoutContext = createContext(null as unknown as {
  setSidebarContent: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<null | React.ReactNode>>;
})

const Layout = () => {
  const [sidebarContent, setSidebarContent] = useState<null | React.ReactNode>(
    null,
  );

  return (
    <LayoutContext.Provider value={{
      setSidebarContent
    }}>

  <div>
    <Sidebar>
      {sidebarContent}
    </Sidebar>
   <div className='page-container'>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <Outlet
      </Suspense>
    </div>
     
  </div>
  </LayoutContext.Provider>)

};

In this example with LayoutContext I provide setter for sidebar content, and I want to know if it will cause some problem with that approach, and if there are any other approaches to set content from child components?

This example is simple enough not to have this problem, but a common issue people find when going down this path is stale closures around values passed to such components.  Overall the structure seems unnecessary.  Why not just store a value in state and conditionally render the JSX based on that value?

Thank you for answer, but this example only has demonstration purpose.
I am actually want to know if there are some technical issues with that apporach ?

And actually my problem is when i have siderbar from top of page, and want to set some content for sidebar from page, can i do that with context api.

"if there are some technical issues with that apporach ?" - What happens when you test it?  Does it work as expected?  Do you observe any problems?  The overall approach may potentially become problematic in other examples as already mentioned, but for the code shown does the approach work for you?  "Best practices" are often a matter of opinion and don't make a significant difference in small enough scenarios.

Sound like an XY problem, what are you actually trying yo do

@PetrosPetoyan: "And actually my problem is..." - What problem?  The question above mentions nothing of this.  If you have another, different question about a specific problem you've encountered in code then you are encouraged to ask a separate question about that.

i edited my  code example, could you see it again please

@PetrosPetoyan you have asked if this is a valid approach, and we've told you no it isn't. There is basically never a reason to store a component in state, David has already mentioned stale closure issues. Your edit still doesn't make any sense, why do you need to store sidebar content in a context provider? You haven't given any reason why that's necessary or even convenient for your use case.

@PetrosPetoyan: "i edited my code example, could you see it again please" - This new code, which is entirely different from the previous code, produces a syntax error and doesn't successfully execute.  Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve?  Or are you just creating random code samples and asking for opinions on them?  Please clarify the question.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

"but I think it is technically is wrong" - Yes, agreed. Storing JSX into React states is a general React anti-pattern, you should store data and then render the JSX from that data. "What you think about that?" - This is subjective and off-topic. Please [edit] to ask a more focused, on-topic, and answerable question.

@DrewReese thanks for your answer, yes agree with you, but i think we can not say that iis anti pattern as react documentation does not say that it is anti pattern

I think the React community would disagree. Trust that it is considered an anti-pattern.

Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919014/is-it-a-good-idea-to-store-components-in-state

@PetrosPetoyan "i think we can not say that iis anti pattern as react documentation does not say that it is anti pattern" I will never understand why some people ask experts for their expertise on some question, have the experts explain patiently the issue, and then they proceed to argue with the experts about the matter without offer any contrary evidence. Why are you trying so hard to salvage this? What personal stake do you have in trying to disagree with the expert opinion you yourself asked for? Do you understand how incredibly arrogant that comes across as?

@Iorweth333 is technically correct, but there are serious pitfalls to watch out for -


function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(<Counter />)
  
  return <div>
    {state} click the counter ✅
    <hr />
    <button onClick={() => setState(<Counter />)} children="A" />
    <button onClick={() => setState(<Counter init={10} />)} children="B" />
    <button onClick={() => setState(<Counter init={100} />)} children="C" />
    change the counter ❌
  </div>
}

function Counter(props) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(props.init || 0)
  return <button onClick={() => setState(_ => _ + 1)} children={state} />
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



The program runs, but changing from one component state to another does not work as we might expect. React detects that state in App changed, but when {state} is rendered, React doesn't know that is a new Counter component, as distinct from any other. So the same counter renders and the state stays the same.
If you re-key the element containing the component stored in state, you can prompt a fresh Counter to be initialized. This is obviously a hack and should be avoided. This demo is only here to give better insight on how React "sees" things -


function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(<Counter />)
  
  return <div key={Math.random() /* hack ❌ */ }>
    {state} click the counter ✅
    <hr />
    <button onClick={() => setState(<Counter />)} children="A" />
    <button onClick={() => setState(<Counter init={10} />)} children="B" />
    <button onClick={() => setState(<Counter init={100} />)} children="C" />
    change the counter ✅
  </div>
}

function Counter(props) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(props.init || 0)
  return <button onClick={() => setState(_ => _ + 1)} children={state} />
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



Now that we can see with React Vision, we can understand why adding a unique key to each Counter component would also "fix" the problem -


function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(<Counter key={0} />)
  
  return <div>
    {state} click the counter ✅
    <hr />
    <button onClick={() => setState(<Counter key={0} />)} children="A" />
    <button onClick={() => setState(<Counter key={1} init={10} />)} children="B" />
    <button onClick={() => setState(<Counter key={2} init={100} />)} children="C" />
    change the counter ✅
  </div>
}

function Counter(props) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(props.init || 0)
  return <button onClick={() => setState(_ => _ + 1)} children={state} />
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



While I haven't seen this explicitly called out as an anti-pattern in the React docs, as seen above, it has potential to hide some bad bugs in your program. For this reason, I think you should avoid storing components as state.

You asked how to make dynamic content another way, we will see that here. In React, we think about state as a snapshot, and our render is made up of props and state, conditional or derived. In this next series of code, we expand our knowledge incrementally, one demo at a time -


function App() {
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState(0) // ✅ state
  return <div>
    <nav>
      <button
        children="About"
        disabled={tab == 0} // ✅ derived props
        onClick={() => setTab(0)}
      />
      <button
        children="Contact"
        disabled={tab == 1}
        onClick={() => setTab(1)}
      />
    </nav>
    { tab == 0 ? <About />
    : tab == 1 ? <Contact /> // ✅  conditional render
    : null
    }
  </div>
}

function About() {
  return <p>About us</p>
}

function Contact() {
  return <p>Contact us</p>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



Above we see how a single number stored in tab can dynamically render content. But what if you want to supply the tabs dynamically? Here we learn how to render lists -


function App(props) {
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState(0)
  const TabFn = props.tabs[tab] // ✅ get tab constructor
  console.assert(TabFn, "tab out of bounds") // ✅ invariant
  return <div>
    <nav>
      {props.tabs.map((TabFn, index) =>
        <button
          key={TabFn.name}
          children={TabFn.name}
          disabled={tab == index}
          onClick={() => setTab(index)}
        />
      )}
    </nav>
    <TabFn />
  </div>
}

function Home() { return <p>Home</p> }
function About() { return <p>About us</p> }
function Contact() { return <p>Contact us</p> }

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(
  <App tabs={[Home, Contact, About]} /> // ✅ dynamic content
)
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



You might be wondering how to get data to our dynamic components. You can pass data deeply with a context. Here we begin adding a "dark mode" to our application. To keep the demo concise, only the nav and Home elements are responding so far -


const defaultContext = { theme: "light" } // ✅ some data

const Context = React.createContext(defaultContext) // ✅ create context

function App(props) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(defaultContext.theme)
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState(0)
  const TabFn = props.tabs[tab]
  console.assert(TabFn, "tab out of bounds")
  return <Context.Provider value={{theme}}>
    <nav className={theme}>
      {props.tabs.map((TabFn, index) =>
        <button key={TabFn.name} children={TabFn.name} disabled={tab == index} onClick={() => setTab(index)} />
      )}
      <button
        onClick={() => setTheme(t => t == "light" ? "dark" : "light")}
        children={`theme: ${theme}`}
      />          
    </nav>
    <TabFn />
  </Context.Provider>
}

function Home() {
  const { theme } = React.useContext(Context) // ✅ access data
  return <p className={theme}>Home</p>
}

function About() { return <p>About us</p> }
function Contact() { return <p>Contact us</p> }

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(
  <App tabs={[Home, Contact, About]} />
)
.dark {
  background-color: mediumblue;
  color: khaki;
}
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



Related: passing JSX as children to a component is normal. Note JSX can be passed in any prop, not limited to children -
<UserProfile
  avatar={<Avatar src={user.avatar} />}
  name={user.name}
  email={user.email}
/>


I'd say this is the expected behaviour - you didn't change the component/element you only changed its props. The change is reflected in props inside Counter.  Me and my team used to encounter similar bugs because state did reset and not because it didn't.
Also, I wouldn't say adding a key is a hack since it's described in official docs as a deliberate way to reset state. The same page explains why the state doesn't reset - the component's function and place in the tree didn't change.

@PetrosPetoyan generally the go-to solution is to store whatever information you need in the context and then creating a SidebarContent component which renders things derived from that information. Do that as long as you can cover all the possibilities in the SidebarContent. If Layout is a widely used component or a library component and can't cover it all, then there is no way other than storing components/elements in the context.

@Iorweth333 I was careful to say "... as we might expect," and I suspect most beginners would, too. You and I have seen behind the JSX curtain and so we know too much. Wisdom informs us when choosing between what is possible and what is pragmatic, ie not anti-pattern. The React docs I linked describe generated keys as a "pitfall". Setting key for other purposes such as the one you describe is valid, and not intended for enabling anti-patterns like storing components in state.

An important distinction needs to be made here: a component is a function of props, state and context which returns an element. What you are storing there in that context is an element. An element is an object of shape specified by React (you can try to console.log it to see it for yourself).
Since you can store both functions and objects in state and context, you can totally store components and elements there too. Also, you can pass them as props.
Given a state:
const [sidebarContent, setSidebarContent] = useState<null | React.ReactNode>(
    null,
  );

And a component
function MyComponent(props) {
  console.log('MyComponent props', props)
  return (
    <div>MyComponent</div>
  );
}

Storing a component in state:
setSidebarContent(MyComponent);

//usage:
<Sidebar>
  <MyComponent prop1={someProp1} prop2={someProp2}/>
</Sidebar>

Storing an element in state (as you did):
//somewhere in a handler or in an effect
setSidebarContent(<MyComponent prop1={someProp1} prop2={someProp2}/>); 

//usage:
<Sidebar>
  {sidebarContent}
</Sidebar>

Passing as props:
<Sidebar
  contentAsComponent={MyComponent}
  contentAsElement={<MyComponent prop1={someProp1} prop2={someProp2}/>}
/>

The major difference is about where you set the props.

"What you are storing there in that context is an element." +1 great call out. "you can totally store components and elements there too" -1, that's a terrible idea and a well-known React antipattern.

@JaredSmith, could you please elaborate?

Your answer contains a really good point about the difference between a component and an element, worthy of an upvote, and a really bad take about storing components and elements in React state, worthy of a downvote, the two cancel each other out so I didn't vote at all (I'm not the DV).

I understand this part, I'm asking about why is that an antipattern. I've searched Google for "React antipatterns" but I didn't find anything like that.

Did you read the accepted answer? And I mean no offense, but I didn't have to search very hard....

I didn't notice the new answwer - I had the page scrolled down, didn't see it. I searched the google for "React antipatterns" assuming that if there was an answer to storing components in state this question would not be posted.

Yeah, that's a dangerous assumption to make on Stack Overflow. Unless it's a relatively new technology most questions have already been asked. I actually found a duplicate for this one, but it's already closed so meh.
